# Density of subspace with nonlocal/Wentzell boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

Given the space $F$ defined by:
$$F=\left\{f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R}):f(x,0)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz, x>0\right\},$$
I want to prove that the subspace $E$ of $F$ defined by $E=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} E_n$ where
$$E_n=\left\{f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R}):f(x,0)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k), x>0\right\}$$ is dense in $F$, assuming that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz$ for all $f$ in $C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R})$, and where $g_n$ and $g$ are positively supported probability distribution functions such that $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges in distribution to $X$ if $X_n\sim g_n$ and $X\sim g$.

The problem essentially comes from the interchange between the first and second components in the nonlocal boundary condition. More precisely, had the problem been to show that $G=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} G_n$ where:
$$G_n=\left\{f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R}):f(x,0)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(x,\frac{k}{n}\right)g_n(k), x>0\right\}$$
were dense in:
$$H=\left\{f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R}):f(x,0)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z)g(z)dz, x>0\right\},$$
it would have sufficed to define the sequence of functions $f_n$ by:
$$ f_n(x,y)=f(x,y)+\frac{y}{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{j}{n}g_n(j)}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(x,\frac{j}{n}\right)g_n(j)\right)$$ to deduce that $f_n(x,0)=f(x,0)$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(x,\frac{k}{n}\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z)g(z)dz$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n-f\|=0$, obviously with the inverted assumption that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(x,\frac{k}{n}\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z)g(z)dz$.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a suitable sequence of functions  to use in my initial problem where the components are interchanged in the boundary condition. Any ideas or references to literature would be greatly appreciated.

Update: As an example, the sequence of functions $f_n$ defined by:
$$ f_n(x,y)=f(x,y)+\mathbb{1}_{\{y>0\}}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,y)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{j}{n},y\right)g_n(j)\right)$$
would verify $f_n(x,0)=f(x,0)$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n-f\|=0$, but $f_n$ is discontinuous (I am looking for a function in $C^2(\mathbb{R}_+^2;\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: If $f \in C(\Bbb{R}^2_+, \Bbb{R})$ how can you consider $$\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz$$ shouldn't it be $$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} f(z,x)g(z)dz \quad?$$

Comment: $F = F_g$? $E_n = E_{n,g_n}$? how do we choose $g_n$ is it a function of $g$?

Comment: @ConradoCosta  I forgot to mention, the two integrals you wrote are equivalent since $g$ is a probability distribution function with positive support

Comment: What about $g_n$? is it related to $g$? in which way?

Comment: @ConradoCosta if we want we can index the spaces by $g$ and $g_n$. The relation between the two is that $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges in distribution to $X$ if $X_n\sim g_n$ and $X\sim g$

Comment: @ConradoCosta for example $g_n$ could be the probability mass function of a geometric distribution with parameter $\frac{\lambda}{n}$ , and $g$ would be the probability density function of an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$ f_n(x,y)=f(x,y)+ \frac{h(y)}{\sum_k h(k/n) g_n(k)}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,y)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{j}{n},y\right)g_n(j)\right)$$

with $h_n(y) = ne^{-1/y}$ if $y>0$ and $h_n(y) = 0$ if $y \leq 0$

then it verifies:

$$\sum_k  f_n(x,k/n) g_n(k)=\sum  f_n(x,k/n) g_n(k)+ \sum_k\frac{h_n(y/n)g_n(k)}{\sum_k h_n(k/n) g_n(k)}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,y)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{j}{n},y\right)g_n(j)\right) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(z,y)g(z)dz $$

$$\|f_n -f \|  \to 0$$

and $f_n\in C^2(\Bbb{R}^2_+, \Bbb{R})$

Comment: thanks for your help man, but I need to find a function $f_n$ which satisfies $f_n(x,0)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)$ (and of course with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_n-f\|=0$. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: In fact the main difficulty I believe comes from the interchange between the variables in the boundary condition, as opposed to the easy case (density of $G$ in $H$) I presented my question

Comment: I will think about it, by the way I don't see how your example $f_n(x,y)=f(x,y)+\frac{y}{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{j}{n}g_n(j)}\left(\int_R f(x,z)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(x,\frac{j}{n}\right)g_n(j)\right)$ satisfies $f_n(x,0)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)$. Maybe that's why I forgot this condition.

Comment: no this is the easy case (density of $G$ in $H$) where $f_n$ satisfies $f_n(x,0)=f(x,0)$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(x,\frac{k}{n},\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,z)g(z)dz$ (no interchange of variables), but I want to prove density of $E$ in $F$ where there is an interchange of variables, so I need $f_n(x,0)=f(x,0)$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz$.

Comment: I found one function which could work $f_n(x,y)=f(x,y)+\mathbb{1}_{\{y>0\}}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,y)g(z)dz-\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} f\left(\frac{j}{n},y\right)g_n(j)\right)$ but it is not even continuous! anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I edited the question (changed the function $h_n(y)$) to match the condition $f_n(x,0) = f(x,0)$. What do you think?

Comment: we still missed the condition $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} f_n\left(\frac{k}{n},x\right)g_n(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(z,x)g(z)dz$. If I am correct. Still on it.

Comment: yes it was a good idea but unfortunately does not satisfy the boundary condition

Comment: But I still don't understand why it is so hard to find a convenient function to prove the density in this case, intuitively this density is an obvious result and there is no problem when the variables are not interchanged